# Selenium run by Jenkins (hosted on Linux machine) failed to read Windows shared folder

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I'm working with Selenium Remote and having an issue about tests run on Jenkins (Linux) always failed.

Those tests run OK on local machine (Windows)

My Current Configuration

- Local: Windows
- Jenkins: Linux
- Selenium Grid: All in Windows

Linux distro

```
cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Log Running Test On Windows

```
2016-03-06 08:36:04,715 INFO  - Exported filename: BW_N0FI31_LastHour_20160306_083604
2016-03-06 08:36:04,715 INFO  - Get export file from Downloads Folder: \\1.2.3.4\Downloads\
2016-03-06 08:36:05,109 INFO  - newest file name : BW_N0FI31_LastHour_20160306_083547.png
```

Log Running The same Test on Jenkins

```
2016-03-06 08:23:10,765 INFO  - Exported filename: BW_N0FI31_LastHour_20160306_082310
2016-03-06 08:23:10,765 INFO  - Get export file from Downloads Folder: \\1.2.3.4\Downloads\
2016-03-06 08:23:10,767 ERROR - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hoang.nguyen.selenium.myapp.myAppUtils.getNewestFile(myAppUtils.java:376)
    at hoang.nguyen.selenium.myapp.myAppBaseTest.checkExportFileName(myAppBaseTest.java:195)
    at hoang.nguyen.keywords.BandwidthMonitor.ExportGraph(BandwidthMonitor.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hoang.nguyen.TestManager.artExecuteScenario(TestManager.java:774)
    at hoang.nguyen.TestManager.artExecutePlan(TestManager.java:738)
    at hoang.nguyen.TestManager.doExecution(TestManager.java:638)
    at hoang.nguyen.TestManager.main(TestManager.java:140)
```

Code of getNewestFile

```
        File dir = new File(folderPath);

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        File[] sortedFiles = new File[files.length];
        if (files.length > 0) {
            Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
                public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                    return Long.valueOf(f2.lastModified()).compareTo(
                            f1.lastModified());
                }
            });
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {// ignore if file is .svn on
                                                    // Jenkins
                String ext = files[i].getAbsolutePath().substring(
                        files[i].getAbsolutePath().length() - 3,
                        files[i].getAbsolutePath().length());
                if (!files[i].isHidden() && !ext.equals("svn")) {
                    sortedFiles[i] = files[i];
                }
            }
            return sortedFiles[0].getName();
        } else {
                return "";
        }
```

Comment: please provide which linux distro u r using.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, it's CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Comment: and i suppose u r running jenkins across network? if that is the case, check your SELinux and firewalld configuration

Comment: PING 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.2.3.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.762 ms. Shared folder access granted. The tests could write files into it but the readDir func failed to read them back.

Comment: Ping works does not mean firewall is not blocking anything. Ping will not be able to tell you which ports are blocked and which process are able to communicate with the files. I understand the kind of pain u r going through ... xD

Comment: Check if the port isn't blocked try `telnet <IP> <PORT>`